# jQuery Toggle next div

Tags: jquery

I have a jQuery script that slides from right to left a div called .inner. But the problem is that is that it will toggle all the divs with class .inner. What I have to do to toggle the .next() .inner?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // This will fire when document is ready:
    $(window).resize(function() {
        // This will fire each time the window is resized:
        if($(window).width() <= 768) {
            // if larger or equal
          $(".myButton").click(function () {

              // Set the effect type
              var effect = 'slide';

              // Set the options for the effect type chosen
              var options = { direction: $().val('right') };

              // Set the duration (default: 400 milliseconds)
              var duration = 500;

              $('.inner').toggle(effect, options, duration);
          });
        } else {
            // if smaller
            $('.element').hide();
        }
    }).resize(); // This will simulate a resize to trigger the initial run.
});
```

Thank you

EDIT:

HTML:

```
<div class="col-xs-1 col-md-1">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-list icons-popover myButton" data-html=true data-popover="true" data-content="                        
    <div class='actions'>
      <a href='#' data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='top' title='Something'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-file'></span></a>
    </div>">
  </span>
</div>
<div class="inner" style="margin-left: 0px;">
        // somethinh                
</div>
<div class="close myButton"><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></div>
```

Comment: $(this).next('.inner')

Comment: It doesn't work with next(). When I apply next my script stops working

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(this).next('.inner').toggle(effect, options, duration);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer:

```
$(".myButton").click(function () {

              // Set the effect type
              var effect = 'slide';

              // Set the options for the effect type chosen
              var options = { direction: $().val('right') };

              // Set the duration (default: 400 milliseconds)
              var duration = 500;

              $(this).parent().next('.inner').toggle(effect, options, duration);

          });
          $(".close").click(function () {

              // Set the effect type
              var effect = 'slide';

              // Set the options for the effect type chosen
              var options = { direction: $().val('right') };

              // Set the duration (default: 400 milliseconds)
              var duration = 500;

              $(this).parent('.inner').toggle(effect, options, duration);


          });
```